# Cube Design in SQL Server 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008

1) I have deployed Cube Successfully but When I am trying to browse it i got this error "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt".
I followed all those steps i.e. create
1)Data Source
2)Data Source Views 
3)Dimension & Measure
4)its(cube)Design

on the other hand

2) When I tried to create New Perspective i got an error "The 'Perspective features' is not included in the 'Standared Edition' SKU." and Deployment failed.
(I'm using my standard edition as a test environment)

I have tried every possible alternative but did not get through.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Perspectives - this feature is available only in Enterprise Edition, Developer Edition and Evaluation Edition of SQL Server.

Memory error: try this
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlanalysisservices/thread/fca63464-cffb-4208-99e4-c0a53c3686a0
(Deepak's answer).

best regards
Grzegorz